# Display the number of days in every month with Java Time

Tags: java, time, java-time

I am trying to display number of days in every month of the year

```
LocalDate start = LocalDate.of(2016, 01, 01);
LocalDate end = start.plusYears(1);
Period everyMonth = Period.ofMonths(1);
for (;start.isBefore(end); start = start.plus(everyMonth)) {
    System.out.println(Period.between(start, start.plus(everyMonth)).getDays());
}
```

Why do I get 12 0s?

Comment: Because you assume that a period of 1 month has any meaning in terms of days without a frame of reference?  ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not using correctly the `Period` class here. `start` represents the date `01/01/2016` (in `dd/MM/yyyy` format). When you are adding a period of 1 month, the result is the date `01/02/2016`.

The period between those two dates, as defined by the [`Period`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Period.html) class is "1 month". If you print the period, you will have [`"P1M"`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Period.html#toString--), which is the pattern to say that:

> A date-based amount of time in the ISO-8601 calendar system, such as '2 years, 3 months and 4 days'.

As such, [`getDays()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Period.html#getDays--), which return the amount of days in the period, will return 0. The result is different than the number of days between the two dates. You can convince yourself of that by printing the result of [`getMonths`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Period.html#getMonths--), it would return 1:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    LocalDate start = LocalDate.of(2016, 01, 01);
    Period period = Period.between(start, start.plus(Period.ofMonths(1)));
    System.out.println(period.getDays());   // prints 0
    System.out.println(period.getMonths()); // prints 1
}
```

---

Now, in your question, you want to print the number of days in every month. You can simply have the following:

```
for (Month month : Month.values()) {
    System.out.println(month.length(Year.now().isLeap()));
}
```

In Java Time, there is an enum [`Month`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Month.html) for all the months, and the method [`length(leapYear)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Month.html#length-boolean-) return the length of this month, i.e. the number of days in the month. Since this depends on whether the current year is a leap year or not, there is a boolean argument for that.

To check for the current year, we can call [`Year.now()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Year.html) and return if it's a leap year or not with [`isLeap()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Year.html#isLeap--).

---

As a side-note, if you truly wanted to print the number of days between two dates, you would need to use `ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(start, end)`.

Answer (score 2):

You are doing everything correctly except one thing. You try to print days in the period, but since you always add 1 month to the date the period is `0 years, 1 month, 0 days`. When you call `getDays()` it returns number of days in period which is 0.

```
final Period period = Period.between(start, start.plus(everyMonth);
System.out.println(period.getDays()); // 0
System.out.println(period.getMonths()); // 1
```

I think what you are looking for is:

```
System.out.println(ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(start, start.plus(everyMonth)));
```